# create stand error page for zuul [version 1.1.2]

Tags: netflix-zuul

I am trying to create standard error page for zuul server so that I can redirect exception to this page?

Currently, I have created a zuul filter to catch zuul exception as below:

**code snippets**

```
 @Override
    public Object run() {
        try {
            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            Object e = ctx.get("error.exception");

            if (e != null && e instanceof ZuulException) {
                ZuulException zuulException = (ZuulException)e;
                LOG.error("Zuul failure detected: " + zuulException.getMessage(), zuulException);

                // Remove error code to prevent further error handling in follow up filters
                ctx.remove("error.status_code");

                // Populate context with new response values
                ctx.setResponseBody("Internal Server Error : Please contact Phoenix Admin");
                ctx.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
                ctx.setResponseStatusCode(500); //Can set any error code as excepted
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception filtering in custom error filter", ex);
            ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

appreciate for any advice?

Comment: changing the content type to text/html should throw a page instead of a json. Is that what you are looking for? or you want to throw an actual page.

Comment: I am expecting the content should be read from error page instead of hardcoding directly into the response body, a option I am thinking is to write a piece of code to read content from file and populate in the responseBody, But I believe there would be a better way to dot it @GrinishNepal

Answer (score 0):

I will have to spend some time to see how you can read from the error page I am traveling right now. But setting the response body by reading content  might not be a bad option definitely might not be perfect.
Checkout the below code if it helps.

Also add some code that you might be trying and is not working its easier that way to answer and help. 
You need to make sure the filter runs after the predecoration filter.

```
  @Override
        public Object run() {
            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8082").path("/outage").build()
                                     .toUriString();
        ctx.set("requestURI", url);
        return null;
    }
```

Check this out for more information:- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1754

Hope this helps you.